# How to analyze kmeans clusters?

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I am working on Kmeans clustering, having some data of students which includes different features including cities they belong and their gpa(s). My data is 43 dimensional.
Using Elbow method, I created 4 different clusters on that data. Now my question is that how I can find on what features I can distinguish these clusters? I tried plotting scatter plots having clusters on x-axis and different features on y-axis but that only defines the range of that one feature in all clusters. And obviously its not always the case that Kmeans distinguish its clusters only on 1 feature when I am creating a model with 43 features. All I am looking is that how can we say that these 4 clusters defines what? I need to label these clusters with some meaningful definition like "Students who are good in studies lies in the 2nd clusters".

Comment: SO is a place for specific programming questions. While your question involves programming, I don't think it is specific enough to be here. It might be better suited for https://datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: Agree that it's off-topic for this stack site. One place to at least start you looking, though, is that you can take the cluster labels, and use them as targets in a logistic regretion, then use standard methods to determine feature weights